# SQL Server : JOIN query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm newbie in SQL Server and I need some help with SQL Server and JOIN method.

My code is:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    p.value AS userposition, 
    p2.value AS usercell, 
    t.id
FROM 
    [es] t
JOIN 
    [user] u ON t.user_uid = u.uid 
JOIN 
    [user] su ON u.superior_uid = su.uid 
JOIN 
    [user_params] up ON t.user_uid = up.user_uid 
LEFT JOIN 
    [params] p ON up.param_id = p.id AND p.name_id = 1 
JOIN 
    [user_params] up2 ON t.user_uid = up2.user_uid
LEFT JOIN 
    [params] p2 ON up2.param_id = p2.id AND p.name_id = 2
```

but it returns duplicated records. I want them just as many as rows in [es] table. In MySQL I would use `GROUP BY t.id`, but in SQL Server that method doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT (clarification):

Thank you for your replies. Maybe I should describe my tables structure and what I need to display.

```
Table [ES]
[id],[user_uid],[more_data]

Table [User]
[uid],[superior_uid],[more_data]

Table [UserParams]
[id],[user_uid],[param_id]

Table [Params]
[id],[param_id],[value]
```

Now what I need is to get all records from [ES] add user data from [User] add his superior data on [User][superior_uid] which is also an [User] record, add [Params] with [Params][name_id] = 1 as value1 AND add [Params] with [Params][name_id] = 2 as value2 ... through [UserParams] if exists.

I think the problem is with JOIN or GROUP BY. [ES] records with users has no [UserParams] are shown only once, but those with [UserParams] are doubled.I tried LEFT OUTER JOIN but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: why do you need all these joins?

Comment: From the looks of it, you don't need the up2, up, u and su joins...
The reason you may see more rows than expected might be because your join-values are not unique.

Comment: I am guessing the user_params is a table that holds the value and the param it is associated with? Does it also have a uid column? Also be careful using top 1000 with no order by. Since you didn't define the order you have no way of knowing what the top x rows will be.

Comment: Which record you want to select if there are several rows per user_id ?

Comment: Hi, I clarified the issue above. Only [User][uid] is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 

p.value AS userposition, 
p2.value AS usercell, 
t.id

FROM [es] t

JOIN [user] u ON t.user_uid = u.uid 
JOIN [user] su ON u.superior_uid = su.uid 

JOIN [user_params] up ON t.user_uid = up.user_uid 
LEFT JOIN [params] p ON up.param_id = p.id AND p.name_id = 1 

JOIN [user_params] up2 ON t.user_uid = up2.user_uid
LEFT JOIN [params] p2 ON up2.param_id = p2.id AND p.name_id = 2

ORDER BY (whichever rows that you want it to be ordered by) ?
```

Answer (score 0):

all of your columns need to be in the group by, or part of an aggregate function

```
p.value AS userposition, #group by or agg func
p2.value AS usercell, #group by or agg func
t.id #group by
```

Wouldnt be certain without knowing what p.value and p2.value actually mean

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure about the joins but I guess you know what you doing, to select distinct row you can use row_number() function as below

```
SELECT  userposition
       ,usercell
       ,id
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1000 
                 p.value   AS userposition 
                ,p2.value  AS usercell
                ,t.id
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.user_uid ORDER BY t.user_uid) rn 
    FROM [es] t
    INNER JOIN [user] u          ON t.user_uid      = u.[uid] 
    INNER JOIN [user] su         ON u.superior_uid  = su.[uid] 
    INNER JOIN [user_params] up  ON t.user_uid      = up.user_uid 
    LEFT  JOIN [params] p        ON up.param_id     = p.id AND p.name_id = 1 
    INNER JOIN [user_params] up2 ON t.user_uid      = up2.user_uid
    LEFT  JOIN [params] p2       ON up2.param_id    = p2.id AND p.name_id = 2 
    ) A
WHERE A.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the last 2 joins by combining them, use `DISTINCT` to not get repeated entries, and use `ORDER BY` to sort it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 
     p.value AS userposition, 
     p2.value AS usercell, 
     t.id
FROM [es] t
JOIN [user] u ON t.user_uid = u.uid 
JOIN [user] su ON u.superior_uid = su.uid 
JOIN [user_params] up ON t.user_uid = up.user_uid 
LEFT JOIN [params] p ON up.param_id = p.id AND (p.name_id = 1 OR p.name_id = 2)
ORDER BY t.id
```